# Throttling POST requests in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, throttling, rate-limiting

I'm using `rack-throttle` as a rate-limiting engine in my rails 3 application. I've created my own class based on the `Rack::Throttle::Interval` to define custom rate limiting logic. I'm checking if the request is made to exact controller and exact action. This works fine if I make `GET` request. However if i send `POST` request i get some problems.

```
class CustomLimiter < Rack::Throttle::Interval
  def allowed?(request)
    path_info = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.url rescue path_info = {} 
    if path_info[:controller] == "some_controller" and path_info[:action] == "some_action"
      super
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my controller actions

```
def question
  #user is redirected here
end

def check_answer
  #some logic to check answer
  redirect_to question_path
end
```

My routes

```
get "questions" => "application#question", :as => "question"
post "check_answer" => "application#check_answer", :as => "check_answer"
```

EDIT:

The problem is that `POST` requests are coming to application so that method `allowed?` is called. But when i call `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` i get a `Route set not finalized` exception. How can i prevent a user from sending a lot of post requests on the exact action of the exact controller with the help of `rack-throttle`

The middleware is added in `application.rb`

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  #Set up rate limiting
  config.require "ip_limiter"
  config.require "ip_user_agent_limiter"
  config.middleware.use IpLimiter, :min => 0.2
  config.middleware.use IpUserAgentLimiter, :min => 2
end
```

Both `IpLimiter` and `IpUserAgentLimiter` are derived from custom limiter

Comment: How have you insert your Rack::Throttle::Interval in your application ?

Comment: @shingara
it's included in `application.rb`

Comment: The allowed? method is call in POST method or not ? Can you pase the part where you add this middleware in your Application ?

Comment: @shingara
Please see edits in the question

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the code of Rails.application.routes.recognize_path ( http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/recognize_path ), this methode get a second args where you can pass the METHOD.

Try with :

```
path_info = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.url, {:method => request.request_method}) rescue path_info = {}
```

After all method can works I suppose.

Comment: I still get the following `RuntimeError: route set not finalized
from /home/rkapitonov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:81:in `recognize'` when tying to do the following `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.url, {:method => request.request_method})`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, to catch all POST requests, and ignore all GET requests:

```
class CustomLimiter < Rack::Throttle::Interval

  def allowed?(request)
    return true unless request.request_method == "POST"
    super request
  end

end
```